# React Lifting Sate Up Through Components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this.  Im writing a dashboard app to play around with in react.  I'm trying to keep things nice and modular.  I have two layout classes "row.js" & "col.js"  They essentially are returning bootstrap responsive grid element, "col-sm-3", etc.

I have created a widget class and a widget-expandable class.  The widget class returns a div with some styles and the widget-expandable class extends the widget class and adds a click handler to expand to the full browser width.  Then I create custom widget classes that extend either of these widget classes.  These custom classes add graphs or tables, etc to the actual component.   The problem im trying to fix is:

In my dashboard.jsx I have:

```
<Row>
    <Col size="sm" num="3"> 
        <SpeakerFees expanded={false}/>
    </Col>
    <Col size="sm" num="9">
        <ProgramStatusByZoneOverview />
    </Col>
</Row>
```

I want to click on the widget component, pass it to the nearest ancestor, "" and alert the other widget(s) in the same row.  According to the react lifting state docs,  we're supposed to lift to the nearest ancestor..in this case two elements up.  This is annoying lol

Because the layout of the dashboard will only contain about a max of 10 total widgets, i figured it was best i just hardcode those out in dashboard.jsx instead of having some kind of loop.  Below are the rest of my classes.

```
dashboard.jsx

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

import { Row } from './layout/row.jsx';
import { Col } from './layout/col.jsx';

import { TotalWidget } from './widgets/total-widget.jsx';
import { ProgramsPlannedBySeries } from './widgets/programs-planned-by-series.jsx';
import { SpeakerFees } from './widgets/speaker-fees.jsx';
import { ProgramStatusByZoneOverview } from './widgets/program-status-by-zone-overview.jsx';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import '../styles/app.scss';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var list = [
            {
                "size": "sm",
                "num": "3"
            },{
                "size": "sm",
                "num": "3"
            },{
                "size": "sm",
                "num": "3"
            },{
                "size": "sm",
                "num": "3"
            }
        ]
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <Row>
                    {list.map(function(object, i){
                        return (
                            <Col key={i.toString()} size={object.size} num={object.num}><TotalWidget key={i.toString()} /></Col>
                        );
                    })}
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col size="sm" num="12">
                        <ProgramsPlannedBySeries />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col size="sm" num="3"> 
                        <SpeakerFees expanded={false}/>
                    </Col>
                    <Col size="sm" num="9">
                        <ProgramStatusByZoneOverview />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col size="sm" num="3"> 
                        <SpeakerFees expanded={false}/>
                    </Col>
                    <Col size="sm" num="9">
                        <ProgramStatusByZoneOverview />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col size="sm" num="3"> 
                        <SpeakerFees expanded={false}/>
                    </Col>
                    <Col size="sm" num="9">
                        <ProgramStatusByZoneOverview />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Dashboard />, document.getElementById('widgets-wrapper'));
```

and my widget classes:

```
widget.jsx
var React = require('react');

import {TweenMax, Power2, TimelineLite} from "gsap";

export class WidgetMenu extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.click = this.click.bind(this);
    }
    click() {
        alert()
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <span onClick={this.click} className={"glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal elipsis " + this.props.state} ></span>
        );
    }
}

export class Widget extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {'scale': false, 'class': ''};
        this.hover = this.hover.bind(this);
    }
    hover() {
        if(!this.state.scale){
            this.setState({'scale': true, 'class': 'scaleUp'})
        }else{
            this.setState({'scale': false, 'class': ''})
        }
    }
    click() {
        // alsert('widget')
    }
    render() {
        return (
              <div onClick={this.click} onMouseEnter={this.hover} onMouseLeave={this.hover} className="widget"><WidgetMenu state={this.state.class} />{ this.props.children }</div>
            )
    }
}
```

and widget-expandable.jsx

```
widget-expandable.jsx
import { Widget, WidgetMenu } from './widget.jsx';
var React = require('react');

export class WidgetExpandable extends Widget {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div onMouseEnter={this.hover} onMouseLeave={this.hover} className="widget"><WidgetMenu state={this.state.class} />{ this.props.children }</div>
        )
    }

}
```

and here are the two custom widgets that would be next to each other is cols/rows in the dashboard.jsx:

```
speaker-fee.jsx
"use strict";
var React = require('react');
var Highcharts = require('highcharts');

import { WidgetExpandable } from './widget-expandable.jsx';

export class SpeakerFees extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <WidgetExpandable handleClick={this.props.handleClick}>
                <div id="speaker-fees-chart"></div>
            </WidgetExpandable>
        );
    } 
}
```

and

```
program-status.jsx
"use strict";
var React = require('react');
import { Widget } from './widget.jsx';

export class ProgramStatusByZoneOverview extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Widget keyId={1}>
                <table className="table" id="speaker-fees-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Speaker Fees, Travel...</th>
                            <th>Budgeted Spend</th>
                            <th>Actual Spend</th>
                            <th>Variance</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Fee For Service</td>
                            <td>250,000</td>
                            <td>150,000</td>
                            <td>-1.5%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Fee For Service</td>
                            <td>250,000</td>
                            <td>150,000</td>
                            <td>-1.5%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Fee For Service</td>
                            <td>250,000</td>
                            <td>150,000</td>
                            <td>-1.5%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Fee For Service</td>
                            <td>250,000</td>
                            <td>150,000</td>
                            <td>-1.5%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Fee For Service</td>
                            <td>250,000</td>
                            <td>150,000</td>
                            <td>-1.5%</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </Widget>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  The key was starting in my row.js class.  I created a click event on the row.js class that set a state of expanded=false on the row class.  Then looped over each child and added this click handler as a prop.  Then added this prop as the onclick of the children.

```
export class Widget extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {'scale': false, 'class': ''};
        this.hover = this.hover.bind(this);
    }
    hover() {
        if(!this.state.scale){
            this.setState({'scale': true, 'class': 'scaleUp'})
        }else{
            this.setState({'scale': false, 'class': ''})
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.onExpandChange)
        return (
              <div onClick={this.props.onExpandChange} onMouseEnter={this.hover} onMouseLeave={this.hover} className="widget"><WidgetMenu state={this.state.class} />{ this.props.children }</div>
            )
    }
}

"use strict";
var React = require('react');

export class Col extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
                (child) => React.cloneElement(child, {
                    onExpandChange: this.props.onExpandChange
                })
            );
        return (
            <div  className={"col-" + this.props.size + '-' + this.props.num}>
                {childrenWithProps}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

"use strict";
var React = require('react');

export class Row extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {expanded: false}
        this.click = this.click.bind(this);
    }
    click() {
        this.setState({"expanded": !this.state.expanded});
        console.log(this.state.expanded);
    }
    render() {
        const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
                (child) => React.cloneElement(child, {
                    onExpandChange: this.click
                })
            );
        return (
            <div className="row">{ childrenWithProps }</div>
        )
    } 
}
```